# Which will be efficient for working with a list of attributes, HashMap or Modal class Array?

Tags: java, performance

I have a list of attributes as follows:

- key
- item1
- item2
- item3

This is one group and I have a number of similar groups like

```
1:       2:       3:        ...........
key_1    key_2    key_3     ...........
item1_1  item1_2  item1_3   ...........
item2_1  item2_2  item2_3   ...........
item3_1  item3_2  item3_3   ...........
```

I need to do some manipulations iterating through the each. Which will be better of the following for performance and space :

**Method 1(HashMap)**:

```
ArrayList(item1,item2,item3)<br>
HashMap(key , ArrayList)      // For each entry
```

**Method 2 (Array of Model class)**:

```
ModelClass
{
key
item1
item2
item3
}[]
ModelClass array
```

Which method would be good for performance?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about efficiency too much until it becomes an issue (or its obvious from the outset that it's a major design decision).

I would favour a correctly modelled object (e.g. your `ModelClass` above). By introducing a new object you can correctly encapsulate your attributes and the mechanism to iterate through these, rather that sore collections of collections and exposing that structure to iterative procedures. Your ModelClass may contain (say) a list of attributes, but that's an implementation decision that you don't have to expose.

Answer (score 1):

Go for [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). More scaleable, readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

> Which method would be good for performance?

It depends on what you do with it. If you look for a particular key, the map will be more efficient. If you always iterate through the whole structure, an array will probably work better (but more complicated to use and still probably not worth the additional pain).

Note that you could also use [a `Multimap<A, B>`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) instead of a `Map<A, List<B>>`.